# PHP OOP vs Procedurial MySQL function reference

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm familiar with creating procedural style PHP functions to select information from a database, but in making the switch to using Object oriented prepared SQL statements, my functions do not work anymore. I do not yet understand OOP as I do procedural PHP, and am trying to learn, so this is my problem:

This works as expected:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT state FROM country WHERE city = ?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $city);
    $city = 'la';
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($state);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
    echo $state;
}
```

Yet, this does not:

```
function get_state( $city ) {
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT state FROM country WHERE city = ?")) {
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $city);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($state);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();
        echo $state;
    }
}

get_state('la');
```

Both examples are requiring a database mysqli connection, yet the function version does not work for some reason, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "does not work"? Is it giving you an error, or just not giving you the expected results?

Comment: @Supericy The first example returns the result from the database, and the function version returns nothing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `$mysqli` is out of scope in the function. You have to declare it as global if you don't want to pass it to the function as argument.

```
function get_state( $city ) {
    global $mysqli;

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT state FROM country WHERE city = ?")) {
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $city);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($state);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();
        echo $state;
    }
}

get_state('la');
```

The variable available outside of the function cannot be accessible in a user-defined function unless it is declared as global or passing it as argument to the function.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do s enable error reporting. That will tell you that you are calling a method (`prepare`) on something that is not a object (`mysqli`), since $mysqli does not exist in the function scope. You will have to pass $mysqli to your function or devise some other mechanism on how the function can access that variable.

Answer (score 0):

`$mysqli` is not defined, I guess. See [manual on scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 0):

pass the `$mysqli` in parameter and also pass the `mysqli` connection object to query.